# log of unsigned long long int argument

Tags: c++, cmath

I need to do the following calculation in a c++ code:

```
(((n*log(n)) / log(4)) + 1)
```

Where n is of type 'unsigned long long int' (and is a power of 2, so result should be integer).

For very large numbers i get some errors e.g for `n = 9007199254740992` result should be `238690780250636289`, but when i run the code i get `238690780250636288`.

Could this be the result of 'log' function not having an implementation with 'unsigned long long int' argument? If so is there a way to circumvent it this without implementing a new log function?

```
unsigned long long int upToBit(unsigned long long int n) {
    unsigned long long int check = (((n*log(n)) / log(4)) + 1);
    return check;
}
```

Comment: JFYI, C++11 allows simplifying calculations: `(((n*log(n)) / log(4)) + 1) = (((n*log(n)) / (2*log(2))) + 1) = n/2 * std::log2(n) + 1`

Comment: Wow, so many parentheses! No wonder I couldn't find any when I needed them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Could this be the result of 'log' function not having an implementation with 'unsigned long long int' argument?

Yes and no.

You use std::log which returns double. double cannot represent 238690780250636289 because of the extended range. If you simply convert that number to long long, you'll get exactly the same error:

```
int main()
{
    volatile double dd = 238690780250636289.0;
    printf("%lld\n", (long long)dd);
}
```

Output:

```
238690780250636288
```

To understand why that happens, there is [a good paper about floating point numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).
You may have luck with long double version of log if sizeof(long double) is > 8 on your compiler. You may also test "correctness" of your computation:

```
bool resultOk = upToBit(9007199254740992) == 238690780250636289.0;
```

In general, double has 52-bit mantissa and because of extra hidden bit maximum reliable integer that double can represent is 2 power 53 or `9007199254740992`. If your resulting double has higher integer value then simple integer math sometimes ["stops working"](http://ideone.com/xr1f5f):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long l = 9007199254740992;
    double d = (double)l;
    d += 1;
    printf("9007199254740992 + 1 = %lld\n", (long long)d);
}
```

Output:

```
9007199254740992 + 1 = 9007199254740992
```

To get better precision you can use some of the multiple precision arithmetic libraries that are designed to do that. GCC for example uses [GMP](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~srirams/courses/csci2824-spr14/gmpTutorial.html) / [MPFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library) for its internal calculations.

Comment: So is there a solution?

Comment: @sniper you *could* use a library like [gmp](https://gmplib.org/) which allows you to do arithmetic on arbitrarily large numbers (exceeding the ranges of the built-in types).